# IDEA can't download sources for my library

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, gradle, maven-publish

I have a library (my own) in a private maven repo. I ship it there with javadoc and sources:

[image: Repo]

In my app I've declared this repo:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
        }
        maven { // <- This is my private repo
            credentials {
                username = extra["mavenUser"] as String
                password = extra["mavenPassword"] as String
            }
            url = uri(extra["mavenUrl"] as String)
        }
    }
}
```

It downloads the aar without any problems, but doesn't download sources, and when I'm trying to force it by clicking «Download sources» it fails:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:DownloadSources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:downloadSources_36c7b334-04c2-4099-b66c-2adc137cc95c'.
   > Could not find com.example.path:common-core:0.0.1@aar.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/example/path/common-core/0.0.1@aar/common-core-0.0.1@aar.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/path/common-core/0.0.1@aar/common-core-0.0.1@aar.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/example/path/common-core/0.0.1@aar/common-core-0.0.1@aar.pom
       - https://repo.replaced-domain.com/mvn/replaced/replaced/com/example/path/common-core/0.0.1@aar/common-core-0.0.1@aar.pom <-- This is my private repo
     Required by:
         project :app
```

**UPD 1:** If I click «Choose sources» and specify my local sources jar, it just does nothing.

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you show where you declared the dependency?

Comment: @Tenfour04 module's `build.gradle.kts` -> `dependencies` -> `api("com.example.path:common-core:0.0.1")`

Comment: @Tenfour04 btw should POM file contain information about sources and javadoc jar?

Comment: From browsing some public POMs, I don't think so. Not an expert on that. I'm not sure what could cause your problem.

Comment: Could you run it with `--debug` key? What exact URL it's trying (and failing) to access?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь well with `--debug` I see the following: `[INFO] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Resource missing. [HTTP GET: repo.replaced-domain.com/mvn/replaced/replaced/com/example/path/common-core/0.0.1@aar/common-core-0.0.1@aar.pom]`. If I remove `@aar` it becomes a valid URL for the POM.

Comment: where does this `DownloadSources` task come from?

Comment: Will it work if you add `metadataSources { artifact() }` to your maven repo declaration (it should disable search for pom files, orienting on artifacts layout)? Or it will try to fetch `common-core-0.0.1@aar-sources.jar` in this case?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь if I add `metadataSources { artifact() }`, it fails to resolve the dependency. `DownloadSources` is the (probably synthetic) name of the task when that is launched when I click «Download Sources» in Idea. It doesn't work for any module from command line, like `./gradlew :core:DownloadSources`

Comment: Variable `extra` is unknown, therefore this is missing debug information; try `project.ext` - or try substituting these variable with strings for a test. In every case, the repository isn't properly set up.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. For some reason the @aar gets placed where it shouldn't in the URL. Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a bug in Android Studio.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247991770
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-302178/Cannot-download-sources-for-AAR-dependencies

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I am not developing with Android Studio currently, but when looking at your output:

```
Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/example/path/common-core/0.0.1@aar/common-core-0.0.1@aar.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/path/common-core/0.0.1@aar/common-core-0.0.1@aar.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/example/path/common-core/0.0.1@aar/common-core-0.0.1@aar.pom
       - https://repo.replaced-domain.com/mvn/replaced/replaced/com/example/path/common-core/0.0.1@aar/common-core-0.0.1@aar.pom <-- This is my private repo
```

it seems that the `ext` (extension) part is not correct resolved/calculated.

Maybe it's enough when you explicit set `ext` inside your dependencies :

```kotlin
build.gradle.kts -> dependencies -> {
    api(group="com.example.path", name="common-core", version="0.0.1", ext="aar")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my own library as well, and I suggest to add a classifier in your artifact that specifically downloads sources and Javadoc. Although it is possibly not necessary, it might help in your case - the two last artifacts specifically bring sources and Javadoc:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.michaelgantman</groupId>
     <artifactId>MgntUtils</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.0.1</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.michaelgantman</groupId>
     <artifactId>MgntUtils</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.0.1</version>
     <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.michaelgantman</groupId>
     <artifactId>MgntUtils</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.0.1</version>
     <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How is this related to Gradle (despite the repo is Maven)?